# Reparametrize the curve problem in Differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Reparametrize the curve $\alpha(t)=(e^{t},e^{-t},\sqrt{2}t), \; \alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$, using $h(s)= \log(s)$ on $J:s>0$.
Check the equation in Lemma in this case by calculating each side separately.

This Lemma : If $\beta$ is the reparametrization of $\alpha$ by $h$, then
$$ \beta' (s)=\alpha'(h(s)) \frac{dh}{ds}(s) .$$

I don't know answer, so I need some help. Please thank you for reading.

Comment: Just reparametrize? No arc length?

Comment: No arc length?. this problem use defintin of reparametrize. I already written h(s)=logs,s>0, anything problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reparametrization you have a map $\beta: \mathbb R_{>0} \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by

$$\beta (s) = \alpha (h(s)) = (s, {1\over s},  \sqrt{2} \log s)$$

For the LHS of the lemma compute $\beta' (s)$ as

$$ \beta' (s) = {d \over ds} \beta (s) = (1, -{1 \over s^2}, {\sqrt{2}\over s})$$

For the RHS of the lemma compute

$$ {d \over ds} h(s) = {1 \over s}$$

and

$$ \alpha '(h(s)) = {d \over dh }\alpha (h) = (e^{h(s)}, -e^{-h(s)}, \sqrt{2})= (s, -{1\over s}, \sqrt{2})$$

and note that

$$ \alpha'(h(s)) \frac{dh(s)}{ds}=   (s,-{1 \over s},{\sqrt{2}}) \cdot {1 \over s} =  (1, -{1 \over s^2}, {\sqrt{2}\over s}) = \beta '(s)$$

as desired.

Comment: I understand when I read your answer

Comment: @Esteban Always glad to help!